# In ruby on rails, how to group records by tag when records have multiple tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using Rails 3.0 and the acts_as_taggable_on gem. I have a Candy model and candies can have multiple tags for flavors. Let's say

```
Candy1.tags #['apple', 'orange']
Candy2.tags #['orange', 'banana']
Candy3.tags #['apple', 'kiwi']
```

I want a list of tags with associated candies below them, like so:

#### Apple

- Candy1
- Candy3

#### Orange

- Candy1
- Candy2

...etc.

I've tried

```
Candy.all.group_by{ |candy| candy.tags }
```

but that treats the array of tags as a single entity, returning something like this:

#### ['apple', 'orange']

- Candy1

#### ['orange', 'banana']

- Candy2

Lacking a group_by_each method, whats the best way to accomplish this? [Another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684441/rails-enumerable-group-by-multiple-associations) explains how to do this in memory with simple hashes, but I wonder if there's a more database-oriented way to do it with ActiveRecord associations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the candies and store them on a hash base on the tag:

```
grouped = {}
Candy.all.each do |candy|
  candy.tags.each do |tag|
    grouped[tag] ||= []
    grouped[tag] << candy
  end
end
```

At the end you will get:

```
{'apple' => [candy1, candy2], 'orange' => [] ...}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: The first and simplest answer--exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
candies = Candy.all.inject({}) do |memo, candy|
  candy.tags.each do |tag|
    memo[tag] ||= []
    memo[tag] << candy
    memo
  end
end
```

Now `candies` is a hash like this:

```
{
  'apple' => [Candy1, Candy3],
  'orange' => [Candy1, Candy2],
  ...
}
```

Which you can iterate over nicely:

```
candies.each do |key, value|
  puts "Candy tag: #{key}"
  value.each do |candy|
    puts " * #{candy}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) documentation that group_by is for collecting enumerable. I think you need to try a more classic array iterator like the following since you've strings data

in views/candy/index.html.erb

```
    <% @candys.each do |candy| %>
    <%= candy.name %>
    <% end %>

    <%for tag in candy.tags %>
     <li> <%= tag.name(or flavor %> </li>    #tag.name_attribute
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

Let me know if it works